# Python - Counting days after/before a date

Tags: python, count

This script is supposed to get a date and number and add or subtract the number from the date and print the new date taking leap years into account and without using the date/calendar function.

It seems that the script does not use the leap_year function properly. using the format DD-MM-YYYY, after feeding the script 01-01-2021 -366 the result should be 01-01-2020 but it gives 31-12-2019 instead

```
   def leap_year(year):
    lyear = year / 4 
    if lyear == 0:
        feb_max = 29
    else:
        feb_max = 28
    lyear = year / 100
    if lyear == 0:
        feb_max = 28
    lyear = year / 400
    if lyear == 0:
        feb_max = 29
    return feb_max

def before(today, num):
    if len(today) != 10:
        return '00-00-0000'
    else:
        str_day, str_month, str_year = today.split('-')
        year = int(str_year)
        month = int(str_month)
        day = int(str_day)

        num = int(num)
        feb_max = leap_year(year)
        mon_max = { 1:31, 2:feb_max, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31}

        while num < 0:
            tmp_day = day - 1

            if tmp_day < 1:
                tmp_month = month - 1               
                if tmp_month < 1:
                    to_day = 31
                    to_month = 12 
                    year = year - 1             
                else:
                    to_day = mon_max[tmp_month]
                    to_month = tmp_month                 
            else:
                to_day = tmp_day
                to_month = month  
                       
            num = num + 1
            day = to_day
            month = to_month

    next_date = str(to_day).zfill(2)+"-"+str(to_month).zfill(2)+"-"+str(year)

    return next_date
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because the `feb_max` in this line `mon_max = { 1:31, 2:feb_max, 3:31, 4:30, 5:31, 6:30, 7:31, 8:31, 9:30, 10:31, 11:30, 12:31}`  is already been fixed to 28 due to year value is 2021, and you are expecting it to be 29 in the while loop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried to put it inside the while loop but it is still the same, and since it is already inside the def function it should not be an issue, correct?

Comment: No, it's not the same thing, you need to dynamically update the `feb_max` value in the while loop, not like the current setup, make it 28 and expecting it to be 29.

Comment: could you show me how I can do that? because I thought it already does that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `/` instead of `%`.

You can use a shorter version:

```py
def leap_year(year):
    is_leap_year = (year % 4 == 0) and (year % 100 != 0) or (year % 400 == 0)
    return 29 is is_leap_year else 28
```

You can also use `datetime` to subtract days

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def before(date, num):
    date = datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%m-%Y")
    sub_date = date - timedelta(num)
    return sub_date.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")

print(before("01-01-2021", 366))
```

Comment: Thank you for the compact version of leap_year function.

as for the datetime function, I know that it works but I would like to find the flaw in this script. somehow the new "year" value after the "if tmp_month < 12" is not being updated within the leap_year function.
I have also tried both / and % and the result is the same.